# Sailsjs distribution across multiple Google compute engine instances

Tags: nginx, sails.js, google-compute-engine, pm2

Sailsjs requires setup to handle scaling horizontally. There are multiple ways to do this. I'm not sure if I have done this correctly, due to poor performance during load testing. Please confirm if I understand and am doing the setup correctly.

- I've created a load balancer on the Google platform for handling the distribution of requests across the instances. Much is spoken about of Nginx for distributing, but I understand Googles load balancer does all I need in this regard. Note, I use session affinity: Client IP.
- I've set up config/session.js to use express-mysql-session, so MemoryStore is not used.
- I haven't set up anything in config/sockets.js. My project doesn't use live chat etc with socket.io, all requests are to waterline for data from db. But if this is a issue, please refer me to a way to do this with Mysql db not redis (or memory).
- I use pm2 as a way to keep it live and to distribute processing on a instance.

Those are the main factors I've found regarding horizontal scaling with sailsjs.